# Redux Toolkit Connect with Javascript Class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, toolkit

I recently integrated Redux ToolKit with my react app. I have this one component that is a JavaScript class, and I'm not sure how to connect redux with it.

I am exporting this class by instantiating the class. (ie: export let class = new Class())

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

From outside of React, you just import your `store` and interact with it. But be aware that there is no mechanism to update your class automatically when a certain store contents changes unless you write one on your own.

Edit: might have read your question wrong.
If you are using a **class component**, you will have to use the `connect` api of `react-redux`.
https://react-redux.js.org/tutorials/connect